# Rails 3.2 message when i execute some instructions: "you did not specify how you would like rails to report deprecation notices"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, plugins, redmine

i'm developing a plugin for redmine and when i'll execute a command to generate a controller i get the following message:

**
c:\redmine>rails g redmine_plugin_controller g_build gbuild_setup
You did not specify how you would like Rails to report deprecation notices for y
our production  environment, please set config.active_support.deprecation to :lo
g, :notify or :stderr at config/environments/production .rb
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/connect
ion_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:47:in `resolve_hash_connection
': database configuration does not specify adapter (ActiveRecord::AdapterNotSpec
ified)
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_r
ecord/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:41:in`resolve_st
ring_connection'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_r
ecord/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:25:in `spec'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_r
ecord/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:129:in`establish
_connection'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_r
ecord/railtie.rb:82:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_
support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in`instance_eval'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_
support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `execute_hook'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_
support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:43:in`block in run_load_hooks'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_
support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:42:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_
support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:42:in`run_load_hooks'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_r
ecord/base.rb:721:in `<top (required)>'
        from c:/redmine/lib/plugins/acts_as_activity_provider/init.rb:2:in`bloc
k in '
        from c:/redmine/config/initializers/00-core_plugins.rb:12:in `eval'
        from c:/redmine/config/initializers/00-core_plugins.rb:12:in`block in <
top (required)>'
        from c:/redmine/config/initializers/00-core_plugins.rb:2:in `each'
        from c:/redmine/config/initializers/00-core_plugins.rb:2:in`'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_
support/dependencies.rb:245:in `load'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_
support/dependencies.rb:245:in`block in load'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_
support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_
support/dependencies.rb:245:in`load'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/engine
.rb:588:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/engine
.rb:587:in`each'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/engine
.rb:587:in `block in <class:Engine>'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/initia
lizable.rb:30:in`instance_exec'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/initia
lizable.rb:30:in `run'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/initia
lizable.rb:55:in`block in run_initializers'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/initia
lizable.rb:54:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/initia
lizable.rb:54:in`run_initializers'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/applic
ation.rb:136:in `initialize!'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/railti
e/configurable.rb:30:in`method_missing'
        from c:/redmine/config/environment.rb:14:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/applic
ation.rb:103:in`require'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/applic
ation.rb:103:in `require_environment!'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/comman
ds.rb:25:in`'
        from script/rails:6:in `require'
        from script/rails:6:in`'

c:\redmine>rails g redmine_plugin_controller g_build gbuild_setup -e devlopment
You did not specify how you would like Rails to report deprecation notices for y
our production  environment, please set config.active_support.deprecation to :lo
g, :notify or :stderr at config/environments/production .rb
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/connect
ion_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:47:in `resolve_hash_connection
': database configuration does not specify adapter (ActiveRecord::AdapterNotSpec
ified)
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_r
ecord/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:41:in`resolve_st
ring_connection'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_r
ecord/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:25:in `spec'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_r
ecord/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:129:in`establish
_connection'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_r
ecord/railtie.rb:82:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_
support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in`instance_eval'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_
support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `execute_hook'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_
support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:43:in`block in run_load_hooks'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_
support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:42:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_
support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:42:in`run_load_hooks'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_r
ecord/base.rb:721:in `<top (required)>'
        from c:/redmine/lib/plugins/acts_as_activity_provider/init.rb:2:in`bloc
k in '
        from c:/redmine/config/initializers/00-core_plugins.rb:12:in `eval'
        from c:/redmine/config/initializers/00-core_plugins.rb:12:in`block in <
top (required)>'
        from c:/redmine/config/initializers/00-core_plugins.rb:2:in `each'
        from c:/redmine/config/initializers/00-core_plugins.rb:2:in`'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_
support/dependencies.rb:245:in `load'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_
support/dependencies.rb:245:in`block in load'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_
support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_
support/dependencies.rb:245:in`load'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/engine
.rb:588:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/engine
.rb:587:in`each'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/engine
.rb:587:in `block in <class:Engine>'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/initia
lizable.rb:30:in`instance_exec'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/initia
lizable.rb:30:in `run'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/initia
lizable.rb:55:in`block in run_initializers'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/initia
lizable.rb:54:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/initia
lizable.rb:54:in`run_initializers'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/applic
ation.rb:136:in `initialize!'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/railti
e/configurable.rb:30:in`method_missing'
        from c:/redmine/config/environment.rb:14:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/applic
ation.rb:103:in`require'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/applic
ation.rb:103:in `require_environment!'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/comman
ds.rb:25:in`'
        from script/rails:6:in `require'
        from script/rails:6:in`'

c:\redmine>rails g redmine_plugin_controller g_build gbuild_setup -e devlopment

> > error.logx
> >     You did not specify how you would like Rails to report deprecation notices for y
> >     our production  environment, please set config.active_support.deprecation to :lo
> >     g, :notify or :stderr at config/environments/production .rb
> >     C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/connect
> >     ion_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:47:in `resolve_hash_connection
> >     ': database configuration does not specify adapter (ActiveRecord::AdapterNotSpec
> >     ified)
> >             from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_r
> >     ecord/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:41:in`resolve_st
> >     ring_connection'
> >             from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_r
> >     ecord/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:25:in `spec'
> >             from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_r
> >     ecord/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:129:in`establish
> >     _connection'
> >             from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_r
> >     ecord/railtie.rb:82:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
> >             from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_
> >     support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in`instance_eval'
> >             from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_
> >     support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `execute_hook'
> >             from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_
> >     support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:43:in`block in run_load_hooks'
> >             from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_
> >     support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:42:in `each'
> >             from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_
> >     support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:42:in`run_load_hooks'
> >             from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_r
> >     ecord/base.rb:721:in `<top (required)>'
> >             from c:/redmine/lib/plugins/acts_as_activity_provider/init.rb:2:in`bloc
> >     k in '
> >             from c:/redmine/config/initializers/00-core_plugins.rb:12:in `eval'
> >             from c:/redmine/config/initializers/00-core_plugins.rb:12:in`block in <
> >     top (required)>'
> >             from c:/redmine/config/initializers/00-core_plugins.rb:2:in `each'
> >             from c:/redmine/config/initializers/00-core_plugins.rb:2:in`'
> >             from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_
> >     support/dependencies.rb:245:in `load'
> >             from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_
> >     support/dependencies.rb:245:in`block in load'
> >             from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_
> >     support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
> >             from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_
> >     support/dependencies.rb:245:in`load'
> >             from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/engine
> >     .rb:588:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
> >             from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/engine
> >     .rb:587:in`each'
> >             from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/engine
> >     .rb:587:in `block in <class:Engine>'
> >             from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/initia
> >     lizable.rb:30:in`instance_exec'
> >             from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/initia
> >     lizable.rb:30:in `run'
> >             from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/initia
> >     lizable.rb:55:in`block in run_initializers'
> >             from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/initia
> >     lizable.rb:54:in `each'
> >             from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/initia
> >     lizable.rb:54:in`run_initializers'
> >             from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/applic
> >     ation.rb:136:in `initialize!'
> >             from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/railti
> >     e/configurable.rb:30:in`method_missing'
> >             from c:/redmine/config/environment.rb:14:in `<top (required)>'
> >             from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/applic
> >     ation.rb:103:in`require'
> >             from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/applic
> >     ation.rb:103:in `require_environment!'
> >             from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/comman
> >     ds.rb:25:in`'
> >             from script/rails:6:in `require'
> >             from script/rails:6:in`'
> >     **

What is the problem? Can anyone help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you made a typo in environment name after -e. In the main thread you got `devlopment` instead of `development`

Answer (score 1):

You did not specify how you would like Rails to report deprecation notices
 for your production environment, please set config.active_support.deprecation
 to :log, :notify or :stderr at config/environments/production.rb

Comment: Hi, i already tried to do it, but didn't work. But no problem, the question was solved with a little help of witchcraft xD. Thanks for your support.

Comment: Care to share how you solved this and accept your own answer?